# Limit as n to infinity: Can I start with let n> c, some c, to simplify?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ be some function. I want to find
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x)^{\frac{1}{c-n}}$$
Can I start with "Let $n>c$" so I don't have to worry about when $c=n$. I think it is fine since the function being weird (or not being defined, etc) at $n=c$ should not affect the limit.

More specifically, with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, if $N> c$ then there should no problem, and if $n\leq c$, I can just use $N'>N$ instead of $N$ since the tail will still be less than $\epsilon$

I just wish to confirm/check.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you may assume $n>c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine, and your reasoning *why* it is fine is spot on.